# Error ";" expected

Tags: java

Quisiera saber porque me esta marcando error de  ";" expected, no soy muy bueno en java, porfavor ayuda
en lal linea 64 o 63
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, acostumbra agregar como texto el còdigo por favor para que sea visible a todos los miembros de la comunidad. Te invitamos a revisar [ask], y realizar el [tour] del sitio, saludos.-

Comment: Tu código es Java amigo que no es lo mismo que JavaScript

Comment: Pues tu error es que esas dos condi iones deberían estar dentro de un par de paréntesis, pues son los que pertenecen al if y no están ahí

Answer (score 1):

Para la estructura IF, se deben encerrar las condiciones dentro de un paréntesis:

```
if ((condicion_1) && (condicion_2)){

}
```

Entonces, lo correcto sería:

```
if ((matriz[0][0] > matriz[0][1]) && (matriz[0][0] > matriz[0][2])) {

}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Erik, ya me funciona